# How to create a (first) child element in XML using Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have an XML element without any children. Its node value is:

```
<property key="TYPES_TO_EXCLUDE_IN_COLLECTOR_PROCESSING"/>
```

And I am trying to create a *first child* of this element and want to set a value to it, e.g. like this:

```
<property key="TYPES_TO_EXCLUDE_IN_COLLECTOR_PROCESSING">
  Some value
</property>
```

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the resulting xml would look like? Also, do you have example code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I improved the formatting of the question and added an example of the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it.

```
String xml = "<property key=\"TYPES_TO_EXCLUDE_IN_COLLECTOR_PROCESSING\"/>";            

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 

InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
Document doc = builder.parse(inputSource);          

Text value = doc.createTextNode("Some value");
Node property = doc.getFirstChild();
property.appendChild(value);

// Could also do the following if you have more than one property element
// You can then refer to any property based on it's position (index)
//NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("property");
//nodes.item(0).appendChild(value);
```